# Develop and deploy on Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm a bit confused on how do we update our nuxt code during run start?

I'm using pm2 to keep the nuxt app running on my server, but let's say I did some changes on my local, pushed it to github and pulled it on my app. When I run build the app on my server, the website hangs, I'm guessing the process is interupting the nuxt server.

Comment: Some error log infos?